# Don't show vote buttons for your own posts

Tags: feature-request, voting

Rather than show a pop-up when you try to vote your own question or answer up or down, just don't show the vote buttons - much like how there's no upvote button on your own comments.

Comment: I think showing the buttons to unregistered visitors without a cookie is even more pointless...

Comment: Doesn't it ask them to sign up so they can vote @DanielBeck?

Comment: @IvoFlipse It's the only privilege that aggressively advertised no people who cannot use it though. There's no `flag`, `close`, `delete` or `protect` either if you don't have the rep for it. *Downvoting* is a *real* privilege though, and that's not even shown in the error message...

Comment: What's the convention on accepting answers on a feature request like this?

Comment: @ChimneyImp: You can still accept any answer you want, if the feature is implemented, your question will be re-tagged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with ChimneyImp. Not many new users come in to Meta to ask that, and those that do will find out very quickly that they simply can't vote on their own question

Answer (score 2):

It has [been asked already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts) on the main Meta site ([several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-are-the-buttons-for-voting-on-your-own-question-or-answer-visible?lq=1) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52729/instead-of-you-cant-upvote-for-yourself-message-wouldnt-it-be-better-to-simp?lq=1))... and declined by the Dev team. So I don't think it will change now.

You can find a [GreaseMonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12708/132632) script on the main question, if you want to remove them for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the Greasemonkey Script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a great idea then we just have to update out [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#reputation) with this that

> You can't upvote your own post even it is answer or question

Or community can point out with a separate FAQ like

> **Why I'm unable to see the Vote button on my own post while others posts I can?**

and the answer could be more powerful then mine

> You can't vote to your own post so you are not able to see those buttons for your own posts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even have enough rep to upvote your question, but I would. I guess it should also be said that if the user does not have enough rep then the upvote button should not be shown

Comment: I disagree, because how else would they know they are eventually expected tovote?

Answer (score -4):

Having the buttons there provides the option for a learning experience.

You click them once (just for fun, of course), and it instantly tells you that you can't do that.

Lesson learned, all is good.

If the buttons were not there in the first place, you might wonder why they aren't there.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how many people would actually ask why they can't upvote their own question. Though each time it came up I would incrementally lose faith in humanity.

Comment: Even when you kept them, for the sake of UI consistency it should at least show the difference between being able to click them or not. And yes, they do have that in there system as the read-only version of the site has different vote buttons...